# Remove Duplicate entries from a 2D list in CSharp

Tags: c#, .net, list, duplicates, hashset

How do I remove duplicate entries from a 2D list in C#.
here is my code.

```
HashSet<List<int>> set =  new HashSet<List<int>>();
set.Add(new List<int>(){1,-2,-1,2});
set.Add(new List<int>(){3,-2,1,1});
set.Add(new List<int>() {1,-2,-1,2}); //duplicate entry
```

but the result i get from this has the duplicate entry `{{1,-2,-1,2},{3,-2,1,1},{1,-2,-1,2}}` i also tried using `set.Distinct().ToList()` but i still get duplicates in my result.

please can someone point me to a neat way to get this done using HashSet. I don't want to compare each sequence in the list because that adds some time complexity to my code.

Thanks for your help in anticipation.

Comment: Is the input really a 2D (aka multidimensional) list (i.e. declared like `int[,] a1 = new int[3,4];`) or is is a jagged array (i.e. declared like `int[][] a2 = new int[3][];`)? The answer will differ depending on what type of array it is.

Comment: its a 2d list so i guess you can also call it jagged array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own implementation of [`IEqualityComparer<List<int>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8) (and use a [`SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.8) method for list equality)

```cs
public class ListComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<int>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<int> x, List<int> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<int> obj)
    {
        return obj.Aggregate(19, (current, item) => current ^ item.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Then pass its instance to [`Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Distinct__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) method

```cs
var set = new HashSet<List<int>>
{
    new List<int>() {1, -2, -1, 2}, new List<int>() {3, -2, 1, 1}, new List<int>() {1, -2, -1, 2}
};

var result = set.Distinct(new ListComparer());
```

It allows you to remove `{1,-2,-1,2}` duplicated entry.

You can also pass `ListComparer` instance to `HashSet` constructor and get rid of adding a duplicate lists

```cs
var set = new HashSet<List<int>>(new ListComparer())
{
    new List<int>() {1, -2, -1, 2}, new List<int>() {3, -2, 1, 1}, new List<int>() {1, -2, -1, 2}
};
```

In example above `set` will contain only two items without duplicated lists

Comment: thanks for your help.. your solution solves my problem. Although I am trying to understand whats happening under the hood. 
I don't know why HashSet doesn't solve my problem out of the box

Comment: @paulmbaike Because you are using a `List<int>` as an item of hash set. By default all reference objects are compared by reference, not by content, so hash set understands all list items as a different items. Therefore you should use custom comparer with `SequenceEqual` method. You can pass `new ListComparer()` to hash set ctor to get an expected behavior, I'll update an answer

Comment: but this implementation works in java. i guess the take away here is "reference objects are compared by reference not by content" thank you so much for the clerification

Answer (score 0):

you can create an implementation of IEqualityComparer and pass it to Distinct function.

in you implementation of IEqualityComparer order the list and check for except (or intersect) if there is any then the two list is not equals.

you can also do a simple loop through each list, and check for item in same index if number of same keys are equal to your list length then eliminate on of them.